# Get Grid Cells Overlapping Parabola

Tags: algorithm, geometry

How do I find all pixels overlapping a parabola (supercover) in an interval defined by two points on the parabola efficiently? All coordinates are integers, grid cells are 1x1 in size.
The parabola is given by f(x) = ax^2 + bx where a and b are known (assume c = 0)

I found this implementation of finding all grid cells overlapping a line. How could it be adapted to use a parabola?
http://playtechs.blogspot.com/2007/03/raytracing-on-grid.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from initial point, then at every step check what cell will be intersected next. This task assumes that pixels are not sizeless points but cells of defined size `S`. Initial cell has coordinates `(0,0)`

Using equation of parabola we calculate intersection of parabola with vertical line `x=S`

```
y = a * S * S + b * S
y_index = floor(y/S)`
```

So we go through the cells `(0,0), (0,1)...(0,y_index)`, then make step right into `(1,y_index)` (`y_index` might be equal zero)

Repeat with intersection with the second level line `y_index_1 = a * 2*S*2*S + b*2*S`, get `y_index1`, mark cells from `(1,y_index)` to `(1,y_index1)` and so on.

Python example

```
import math
def markcells(a, b, S, xmax):
    newy = 0
    oldy = 0
    step = 0
    while step * S <= xmax:
        step += 1
        edgex = step * S
        newy = math.floor((a*edgex*edgex + b*edgex)/S)
        lst = []
        for y in range(oldy, newy + 1):
            lst.append([step - 1, y])
        print(lst)
        oldy = newy

markcells2(0.05, 0.1, 1, 5)

[[0, 0]]
[[1, 0]]
[[2, 0]]
[[3, 0], [3, 1]]
[[4, 1]]
[[5, 1], [5, 2]]
```

P.S.
I omitted case when parabola goes exactly through cell corner (when `y/S` is integer) - choose wanted strategy for such cases: either mark aside cells or not (for example, parabola `y=x*x` for `x=2`: should we mark `(3,4)` and `(4,3)`?)

Comment: If the parabola is too steep then the parabola can move up and down through cells in the same step at the grid x-coordinate where the peak is located. In that case, this code will miss some grid cells.

Comment: It is worth to calculate parabola vertex x-coordinate `xv=-b/2a`, corresponding y-coordinate `yv=-b^2/4a+c` and make separate calculations for left and right branches of parabola

Comment: Yes, but simply calling markcells twice will not work. One way to do it is to move the loop to another function. In markcells, execute the loop for xmax = min(xmax, xv), then execute the body of the loop for edgex = xv and afterwards execute the loop with actual xmax as xmax.